# Low res vertical photos using Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, batch-processing, cs5, raw-format

I´m using `.raw` files in CS5 and saving them to `.jpg` and they are all unedited...

The portrait photos are all being compressed and have low res while the landscape ones are fine, why is that? I have reset my setting in CS5 with no result. I just processed 200 photos for a client and half of them (all portrait ones) won´t print larger than a 4x6.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a max pixel value on height? Did you record it as an action on a horizontal and then batch the whole group?

What I'm getting at is: Sounds like you are using the Image Processor script, and your vertical shots are getting reprocessed down to the height of the horizontals.